# disable MenuItem in windows phone toolkit

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-phone-7.1, toolkit

I want to disable some menuItems in a contextMenu, but not all of them.

```
 <tk:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <tk:ContextMenu Name="optionMenu">

                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Move to Favorite" Name="moveToFav" Click="moveToFav_Click" />
                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Copy to Favorite" Name="copyToFav" Click="copyToFav_Click" />
                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Set as Folder Front" Name="setFront" Click="setFront_Click" />
                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Delete" Name="delete" Click="delete_Click" />
                            </tk:ContextMenu>
                        </tk:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

for example, I want to disable moveToFav, copyToFav MenuItem, I try to

```
moveToFav.isEnabled = false; copyToFav.isEnable = false;
```

But It didn't work because the compiler said moveToFav doesn't exist in the current context.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I decided to do the following

```
<tk:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <tk:ContextMenu x:Name="optionMenu" >

                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Move to Favorite" x:Name="moveToFav" Click="moveToFav_Click" Loaded="moveToFav_Loaded" />
                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Copy to Favorite" Name="copyToFav" Click="copyToFav_Click" Loaded="copyToFav_Loaded" />
                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Set as Folder Front" Name="setFront" Click="setFront_Click" Loaded="setFront_Loaded" />
                                <tk:MenuItem Header="Delete" Name="delete" Click="delete_Click" />
                            </tk:ContextMenu>
                        </tk:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

in the code:

```
private void moveToFav_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (condition)
            (sender as MenuItem).IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void copyToFav_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (condition)
            (sender as MenuItem).IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

it's not perfect, but it works